# Checkbox Select All functionality showing opposite behaviour after triggering click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below javascript code which dynamically add the DIV with checkbox.

```
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.className = 'field';

var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'SelectAllCheckBox';

var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
newlabel.innerHTML = "Select All";

var selectCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
selectCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
selectCheckbox.name = "selectCheckbox";
selectCheckbox.id = "selectCheckboxID";
selectCheckbox.checked = true;

innerDiv.appendChild(selectCheckbox);
innerDiv.appendChild(newlabel);

mainDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

var BusinessUnitsContainerID = document.getElementById('BusinessUnitsContainer');
BusinessUnitsContainerID.parentNode.insertBefore(mainDiv,BusinessUnitsContainerID);
//$j('.Publications input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
$evt.addEventHandler(selectCheckbox, "click", this.getDelegate(this._onSelectAllCheckBoxClick));

function _onSelectAllCheckBoxClick()
{
    //(.Publications input[type=checkbox]) these are multiple checkboxes which are also created dynamically
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.Publications input[type=checkbox]');   

    for (var i =0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
    {
        checkboxes[i].checked = $j("#selectCheckboxID").checked;
        $j(checkboxes[i]).click(); //calling the click for the child checkboxes as they have there click event and I can't change that as it is application generated click event for them.
    }    
};
```

Don't know why my select all check box it behaving differently, now on first click it is not unchecking all the child checkboxes, however on second click it works fine.

Any idea what could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

```
//alert("Inside Select All");
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.Publications input[type=checkbox]');   

    //alert($("#selectCheckboxID").checked);
    if($("#selectCheckboxID").checked)
    {
        for (var i =0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;           
            $j("#lblSelectAll").text("Check All");
            $j(checkboxes[i]).click();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i =0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
        {
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            $j("#lblSelectAll").text('Uncheck All');  
            $j(checkboxes[i]).click();
        }
    }
```

Above code I have written to test, how to make it short

Comment: Oh God! You're using jQuery, but the only line of jQuery is `$j("#selectCheckboxID").checked;`, which is wrong !

Comment: yeah this is sample code however on other places this is used maximum

Comment: what happens on first click? are all selected or no change at all?

Comment: On the page load all the (.Publications input[type=checkbox]) are checked by default and mine "Select All" also checked, however when I click first time, there is no changes and in second time it uncheck all (.Publications input[type=checkbox]), however now my "Select All" shows checked, something vice versa happening

Comment: Added the another code sample to work any idea how can I short it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `_onSelectAllCheckBoxClick` function with below and try

```
function _onSelectAllCheckBoxClick()
{
    $('.Publications input[type=checkbox]').click(); // jQuery default selector format
    // if above doesn't work use your format, comment above code and uncomment below code
    // $j('.Publications input[type=checkbox]').click();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What this code will do? I need to have check all and uncheck all functionality as well

Comment: It will `check` and `uncheck` all child `checkbox` in Publications `class`